# mvvm light : call method in viewmodel from view

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I am working on Universal app actually, I want to call a method in the viewmodel from the view to update the data to display.

In my viewmodel :

```
public async void GetDateScore(DateTime dt)
{
    string date = dt.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    List<Score> scoreList = await HtmlGetterHelper.GetLastNightScore(date);
    LastScore = new ObservableCollection<Score>();

    for (int i = 0; i < scoreList.Count; i++)
    {
        LastScore.Add(scoreList[i]);
    }
}
```

I try to call it with `base.GetDataScore(DateTime.Today)` but it doesn't work.
I don't know if it's possible to call the method with something like this or if I should use the messenger of MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is my *opinion*, that your scenario is consequence of a wrong turn along the way, you could use the service locator to solve your problem:

```
var vm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TypeOfObject>();
// do something with viewmodel
```

This is possible, because MVVM Light does this `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);` when it adds the ViewModelLocator file.

for *MVVM Light* specifically, you can use (should behave the same as above):

```
var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<SomeViewModel>();
// do something with viewmodel
```

of course you have to register it first:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SomeViewModel>();
```

Comment: Ok, I think I can make something with this, but I just want to know if it's possible to do something better. To be clear, I have an html parser who take an url and return an object, all day data (it's an app about sports score) was on specific page like http://www.example.com/yyyyMMdd when I click on different date on calendar, I want to update the data in the viewmodel, do you think there is a better way to do this? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well if you have 2 way binding, you could bind the calendar date to a property in you ViewModel, and  a new date will raise `OnPropertyChanged` event in ViewModel, so you will be able to perform the necessary action and then update the property that binds to the `AllDayData`.

Comment: Ok, I think I gonna try this way! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of any help!

Answer (score 0):

if that viewmodel is datacontext of view you can do it like in this way:

```
await (DataContext as YourViewModel).GetDataScore(date);
```

But I recommend using commands without code behind:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetDataSourceCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=YourTextBox, Path=Text}" />
                    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and in viewmodel:

```
public RelayCommand<DateTime> GetDataSourceCommand
{
    get { return _getDataSourceCommand ?? (_getDataSourceCommand = new RelayCommand<DateTime>(GetDataSource)); }
}
```